# Android ORMlite - more than one table / classes

Tags: android, ormlite

I have a problem by using the ORMlite framework with more than one table / classes.

I´ve got one DatabaseHelper.class which extends the OrmLiteSqliteOpenHelper which looks like this (important parts):

```
public class DatabaseHelper<T> extends OrmLiteSqliteOpenHelper {

    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "database.db";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 6;

    private Dao<T, Integer> myDao = null;
    private Class<T> type;

    public DatabaseHelper(Context context, Class<T> type) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        this.type = type;
    }
    
    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db, ConnectionSource connectionSource) {
        try {
            TableUtils.createTable(connectionSource, type);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    public Dao<T, Integer> getmyDataDao() throws SQLException {
        if (myDao == null) {
            myDao = getDao(type);
        }
        return myDao;
    }
}
```

I use 2 classes (Admin1, Admin2) in which I want to save 2 different objects (Object1, Object2) in the database. Here the code I used for this.

Amin1:

```
static {
    OpenHelperManager.setOpenHelperFactory(new SqliteOpenHelperFactory() {
        public OrmLiteSqliteOpenHelper getHelper(Context context) {
            return new DatabaseHelper<Object1>(context, Object1.class);
        }
    });
}

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.object1);
    Dao<Object1, Integer> myDaoObject1 = getHelper().getmyDataDao();
    Object1 o1 = new Object1("Name of Object 1");
    int ret = myDaoObject1.create(o1);
}
```

Admin2:

```
static {
    OpenHelperManager.setOpenHelperFactory(new SqliteOpenHelperFactory() {
        public OrmLiteSqliteOpenHelper getHelper(Context context) {
            return new DatabaseHelper<Object2>(context, Object2.class);
        }
    });
}


protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.object2);
    Dao<Object2, Integer> myDaoObject2 = getHelper().getmyDataDao();
    Object2 o2 = new Object2("Name of Object 2");
    int ret = myDaoObject2.create(o2);
}
```

It works fine for the first object I save (in Admin1 or Admin2). But if I save object1 in Admin1 and after that I want to save object2 in Admin2 or reverse (the order is not decisive), I get following error in the line "int ret = myDaoObject2.create(o2);":

```
Unable to run stmt on object com.example.Object2@44c408f0: INSERT INTO `object2` (`name` ) VALUES (?)
```

There is no error in creating the Object2 o2 in the code. Not before the line "int ret = myDaoObject2.create(o2);" the error occurs ... I have no idea why there is an "?" in the value. One line before the object looks fine.

Has anybody an idea?

Thanks a lot!

**Update**

Unfortunately I couldn`t solve the problem.

I´ve tried now to close the OrmLiteSqliteOpenHelper at the `onPause()` and/or at the `onStop()` of the activitiy:

```
myHelper.close();
```

Since then I get the error:

> "Unable to destroy activity - null pointer exception"

I can't understand this error.

Does anybody have an idea?

Comment: Please just edit your question to provide additional information, or use the comment facilities under the individual answers to ask for clarification.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Isn't your DB file completely rewritten on admin2 initialization?
Do you really need two different Helper instances? If you just need to have two different dao objects for them - use one shared helper and just add a new getAdmin2Dao method.

HTH

EDIT (Adding some code):

```
 private Dao<Profile, String> profileDao = null;
 private Dao<Network, String> networkDao = null;

 @Override
 public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db, ConnectionSource connectionSource) {
            try {
                    Log.i(DBHelper.class.getName(), "onCreate");

                    TableUtils.createTable(connectionSource, Network.class);
                    TableUtils.createTable(connectionSource, Profile.class);

            } catch (SQLException e) {
                    Log.e(DBHelper.class.getName(), "Can't create database", e);
                    throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
 }

 public Dao<Profile, String> getProfileDao() throws SQLException {
    if (profileDao == null) {
       profileDao = getDao(Profile.class);
    }
    return profileDao;
 }

 // ... Same for the other DAO

 @Override
 public void close() {
    super.close();

    networkDao = null;
    profileDao = null;
 }
```

Comment: i'm not shure whether i need 2 different helper instances. i just need to get data (objects) from different tables of the database in different actions ... unfortunately i dont know the best practise. can you give me some more details or example code of your hint please? thnx!

Comment: this was helpful. my first intention was to solve this problem with generics, but this is ok too i think! i`ll use it! thank you! ;)

Comment: This is spot on Alex thanks.  @SKAf8ce you should definitely only have 1 helper and one connection to the database.  If you look at the Android ORMLite examples, you can see that they all use the same helper: http://ormlite.com/docs/android-examples

Answer (score -1):

I got this error 2 days ago and I just solved this night :) When you create your first Object, You can  do any database operations but when you want to create another object  and doing some operations like add or delete or etc..you get an error because Database helper Doesn't create second object(TAble).Firstly,  when you open your Application you have to create  your objects(TAble classes) like below

```
TableUtils.createTable(helper.getConnectionSource(), BudgetCategory.class);
....
....
```